# Why does my fifo read return strings with weird characters in the middle?

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to pass logging statements to a daemon process via a named pipe. The statements contain the timestamp, the sender and the message. The messages are created just as they are supposed to but when I read them from the other end of the pipe, they sometimes have weird characters in the middle of the string such as `Úèþ`. I tried appending the `'\0'` to the end of each logging statement but it didn't have any effects. Below is the code of my pipe creation and the reading part:

```
char * fdfifo = "./fifo/myfifo";
    mkfifo(fdfifo, 0666);
    int fd = open(fdfifo,O_RDONLY);
    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = 5;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    logger(getpid(), pthread_self(), "logger started");
    while(1 && keepRunning){
        fd_set fds;
        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        FD_SET(fd, &fds);
        if(select(fd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout)<=0){
            logger(getpid(), pthread_self(), "stopping logger");
            close(fd);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            break;
        }
        else{
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock2);
            FILE *f = fopen("./log/log.log", "a");
            char concat_str[200];
            read(fd, concat_str, 200);
            fprintf(f, "%s\n", concat_str);
            fclose(f);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock2);
        }
    }
```

And this is the part where I am writing to the pipe:

```
int startLoggerEnd(){
    readfifo = "./fifo/myfifo";
    mkfifo(readfifo, 0666);
    writedesc = open(readfifo,O_WRONLY);
    sleep(2);
    return 0;
}

int logger(pid_t pid, pthread_t tid, char *message){
    char tmp[100];
    char buff[20];
    char msg[200];
    struct tm *sTm;
    time_t now = time (0);
    sTm = gmtime (&now);
    strftime (buff, sizeof(buff), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", sTm);
    sprintf(msg,"%s %s %d %s %d %s %s\n", get_timestamp(tmp), "process:", pid,
            "thread:",(unsigned) tid, "||", message);
    write(writedesc, msg, strlen(msg));
    return 0;
}
```

And few lines from the end of the logfile:

```
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:41:729 process: 14736 thread: 127881216 || moi
13:29:
```

Comment: In your routine `logger`, (a better name would be `log` (as that is what it does)), you create a fifo (not a pipe), each time. Re-creating the fifo, will cause no end of problems, it may be causing your problem.

Comment: Should I create the fifo when daemonizing the recieving end (an thus creating the fifo only once)?

Comment: You should create the fifo in the **service**, when it starts. (the fifo provides the service, so should be created and bound to it, by the service, it should only be removed as the service is exiting). If you are using fork to create the two processes then use a pipe (not a fifo). See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68146/4778 (you won't need locks if you keep the messages small, which you have (≤512 bytes is guaranteed to be small enough).

Comment: Trying to create a fifo with a name that already exists in the filesystem will fail with an error, but you're not doing any error checking or reporting.... But yes, you should only create it once.

Comment: And renaming that logger() function to log() would conflict with the standard function of that name. Don't do that.

Comment: I have just spotted a memory leek, and some un-necessary copying.

Comment: You also have a memory leak where you never free the memory you allocate for `str2`. Why are you doing that anyways? Just write the contents of `msg` directly.

Comment: I was going to compile it, and run in debugger, but it does not compile.

Comment: I think the main error is that you do not write the null character which closes the string to the pipe: `write(fd, str2, strlen(str2));` will only write up to, but excluding the terminating null. That should fix this particular problem ;-). (Allocating the target buffer with `calloc` fixes it too, but is unnecessary.)

Comment: Anyways, you're getting funky characters because you assume that every read into concat_str is a 0 terminated string, which is not the case - you're not writing 0 terminated strings to the pipe, and you're ignoring read()'s return value telling you how many bytes were read each time.

Comment: Of course Shawn is correct that you make a lot of assumptions which are often, but not always true (like that you have corresponding, complete `read`/`write` pairs). Depending on the data length and the nature of the file descriptor (socket, network file?) you write to and read from you may encounter incomplete writes and reads and you have to structure your data so that you know when a "record" of some kind is finished. One of the simplest is to embed newlines in the sent data and make the contract between sender and receiver that data consists of complete lines.

Comment: I've changed the message creation to `sprintf(msg,"%s %s %d %s %d %s %s\n", get_timestamp(tmp), "process:", pid,
            "thread:",(unsigned) tid, "||", message);` and I am now opening the writing end of the file descriptor in another function and keeping it open until the end of logging. The file looks better now but the end of the file is still a mess

Answer (score 2):

You are currently displaying an allocated slice of memory (str2).

However, you don't make sure that the portion of memory that you've requested is empty.

It may contains bytes of previous operations, resulting in a bad display.

The correct way to assure that you are not displaying previous bytes is to clean the memory before printing it.

```
char *str2 = calloc(strlen(msg) + 1, sizeof(char));
strcpy(str2, msg);
str2[strlen(msg)] = '\0'; // index start at 0, strlen start at 1
write(fd, str2, strlen(str2));
close(fd);
```

calloc will clean the memory allocated before returning it to you.

Also, be aware that this code suffers a major leak of memory, you doesn't even free the str2 that you have allocated.

Comment: If you make `msg` one byte longer, then there is no need to do the copy.

Comment: There is also no need to overwrite the null byte at the end of a string copied with `strcpy` with another null byte ;-). The meaning of `strlen` is to return the index of the first null byte after the given address; you *can* take that index and replace the found null byte with a new value of null to be really, really sure; but it's kindof redundant ;-).

Comment: What *does* make sense though and is often essential, by contrast, is to put strategically placed null bytes in the *source* data of a `strcpy` (for which it is necessary to have some information from elsewhere about the length or at least max length of the source data). The OP's code is a good example for it: He forgets to write the trailing null in the byte stream on the write side; it's just good luck that a null byte happens to lurk somewhere in the allocated memory of the read side.